# How to add an html attribute to configurable product with select element in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to add an attribute to configurable product select element in Magento 2.

Now:

```
<select name="super_attribute[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]"
                        data-selector="super_attribute[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]"
                        data-validate="{required:true}"
                        id="attribute<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>"
                        class="super-attribute-select <?php echo $id; ?>">
                    <option value=""><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
                </select>
```

What i want:

```
<select name="super_attribute[136]" data-selector="super_attribute[136]" data-validate="{required:true}" id="attribute136" class="super-attribute-select color" aria-required="true">              
          <option  value="">Choose an Option...</option>
          <option data-class="Red" value="75">Red</option>
          <option data-class="Teal" value="61">Teal</option>
          <option data-class="Black"value="4">Black</option>
          <option data-class="Ivory" value="8">Ivory</option>
    </select>
```

Thanks.

Comment: data-class="" values are dynamic ?

Comment: @Shafeel Yes - I want to add it based on the value ex. color: Red, Teal, Black, Ivory

Comment: now how can you print the colors ? ex:red ... , can you please comment the code ?

Comment: @Shafeel I have updated the question. Please check